# iterating through csv dataframe to create/assign variables

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, iteration

I have a csv file that will contain a frequently updated (overwritten) dataframe with a few rows of purchase orders, something like this:

```
uniqueId    item      action    quantity    price
123         widget1   buy       10          99.44
234         widget2   sell      15          19.99
345         widget3   buy       2           999.99
```

This csv file will be passed to my python code by another program; my code will check for its presence every few minutes.  Once it appears, the code will read it.  I'm not including the code for that, since that's not the issue.

The idea is to turn this purchase order dataframe into something that I can pass to my (already written) place-the-order code. I want to iterate through each row in order (enumerate?), and assign the values from that row to variables that I use in the order code, then reassign the new values to the same variable for the next row after the order from that row has been placed.

As I understand it, **itertuples** are probably the way to go for iterating through it, but I'm new enough to python that I can't figure out the actual mechanism/syntax of using it to do what I want.  All my trial-and-error tests for assigning the values to reusable variables result in syntax errors.

I'm having a mental block on what is probably very basic python!  I know how to iterate through the rows and print 'em out--plenty of examples out there show me how to do that--but not how to turn the data into something I can use elsewhere.  Can someone walk me through an example or two that actually applies to what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like you said, you can quite easily iterate over a dataframe with `.itertuples()`

Here's how I would go about it (`df` is your dataframe; for it I used the data from your example):

Code:

```
for row in df.itertuples():
    print(row)
```

Output:

```
Pandas(Index=0, uniqueId=123, item='widget1', action='buy', quantity=10, price=99.44)
Pandas(Index=1, uniqueId=234, item='widget2', action='sell', quantity=15, price=19.99)
Pandas(Index=2, uniqueId=345, item='widget3', action='buy', quantity=2, price=999.999)
```

---

If you want to get specific entries of the tuples you need to use the position in the tuple as index:

Code:

```
for row in df.itertuples():
    uniqueID = row[1]
    print(uniqueID)
```

Output:

```
123
234
345
```

I'm not sure how the rest of your code looks like. If you have the place-the-order code inside a function you could just call the function in the for-loop after assigning the variables to your liking:

```
for row in df.itertuples():
    uniqueID = row[1]
    item = row[2]
    action = row[3]
    quantity = row[4]
    price = row[5]
    place-the-order(uniqueID, item, action, quantity, price)
```

(You could even skip assigning the variables and just call `place-the-order(row[1], row[2], ...)`. In my opinion it is more readable to assign the variables.)

---

If your place-the-order code is not in a function I would recommend using a nested dictionary with the row index as key and a dictionary of the content of the row as value. The row index is easily accessible as it is the first item in the tuple.

```
content_of_rows = {}
for row in df.itertuples():
    index = row[0]
    uniqueID = row[1]
    item = row[2]
    action = row[3]
    quantity = row[4]
    price = row[5]
    content_of_rows.update({index:{"uniqueID":uniqueID, "item": item, "action": action, "quantity": quantity, "price": price}})
print(content_of_rows)
```

Output:

```
{0: {'uniqueID': 123, 'item': 'widget1', 'action': 'buy', 'quantity': 10, 'price': 99.44}, 
1: {'uniqueID': 234, 'item': 'widget2', 'action': 'sell', 'quantity': 15, 'price': 19.99}, 
2: {'uniqueID': 345, 'item': 'widget3', 'action': 'buy', 'quantity': 2, 'price': 999.999}}
```

This way you can't use the same variable for every row, since it's generally speaking just a different way of writing a dataframe. You can iterate over dictionaries pretty much the same as over tuples but instead of numerical indices you have to use the key.

```
for row in content_of_rows:
    # row is the key, so in the first iteration it would be 0, in the second iteration it would be 1, and so on 
    print(content_of_rows[row])
```

Output:

```
{'uniqueID': 123, 'item': 'widget1', 'action': 'buy', 'quantity': 10, 'price': 99.44}
{'uniqueID': 234, 'item': 'widget2', 'action': 'sell', 'quantity': 15, 'price': 19.99}
{'uniqueID': 345, 'item': 'widget3', 'action': 'buy', 'quantity': 2, 'price': 999.999}
```

If you want to get the uniqueID of the rows, you would do something like this:

Code:

```
for row in content_of_rows:
    print(content_of_rows[row]["uniqueID"]) # just put the second key you're looking for right after the first, also in []
```

Output:

```
123
234
345
```

---

It's usually best to put different parts of your code into functions, so if you haven't done that already I'd recommend you do so. That way you can use the same variables for each row.

I hope this (kinda long, sorry about that) answer could help you. Greetings from Bavaria!

Comment: I haven't had the chance to try putting this into practice yet, but from reading over it I think I should be able to make it work--thanks for the nice long answer!